# My Android ListView item layout looks terrible

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

I wanted to create a layout like the CyanogenMod call log in that there is a list item with a couple of views and a clickable button on the right which gets focus separately ([screenshot](http://i55.tinypic.com/358s1lc.jpg)).  Instead, I get [this mess](http://i55.tinypic.com/im4f2t.jpg).

Here's my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
    >

    <DontPressWithParentImageView android:id="@+id/play_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="14dip"
        android:paddingRight="14dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/sym_play"
        android:background="@drawable/play_background"
        />

    <View android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/play_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:background="@drawable/divider_vertical_dark"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/file_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/file_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/file_info"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For reference, the code I started with is [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Contacts/blob/froyo-stable/res/layout-finger/recent_calls_list_item.xml) and [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Contacts/blob/froyo-stable/res/layout-finger/recent_calls_list_item_layout.xml), and the source to `DontPressWithParentImageView` is [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Contacts/blob/froyo-stable/src/com/android/contacts/ui/widget/DontPressWithParentImageView.java) (but as you can see from my screenshot, that part is working).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using two `LinearLayout`s instead of a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/file_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/file_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:background="@drawable/divider_vertical_dark"
        />

    <DontPressWithParentImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/sym_play"
        android:background="@drawable/play_background"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```